# ¿Cómo llamar una función de javascript en el evento oninput usando Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular, ionic2

Lo que hace es que define un máximo y mínimo al `input` si el valor es ingresado por teclado. Resulta que funciona perfecto, pero después de eso quiero llamar a una función y me arroja un error de función no definida.

Por medio del evento `(change)=" xFuncion();"` no me arroja el error, pero el asunto aquí es que este evento no se llama hasta que el `input` pierda el *focus*.

Necesito un evento que funcione como `oninput`, que sea llamado apenas detecte un cambio en el `input` y que tenga el alcance de la función `xFuncion();`.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<input
    type="number"
    name="x"
    min="0"
    max="50"
    oninput=" if (value > 50) { value = 50; } else if (value < 0) { value = 0; }; "
    class="cantidad"
    [(ngModel)]="producto.cantidad"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el evento [(keyup)](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object) de Angular 2

[Ver Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/dYUbPfR1VWNHZmBuENUa/)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type="number"
                    value=""
                    [(ngModel)]="cantidad"
                    (keyup)="xFunction()">`,
})
export class App {

  cantidad: number;

  constructor() {
  }

  xFunction() {

    console.log(this.cantidad);

    if (this.cantidad > 50) { 

      this.cantidad = 50; 

    }
      else if (this.cantidad < 0) {

        this.cantidad = 0; 
    }
  }
}
```